# Time from parts

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

```
Select TimeFromParts(FieldName/ 10000,(FieldName / 100 % 100, % 100, 0, 0)
```

Could someone explain this select statement and what exactly each argument is doing?
I see this is used to change an integer to time but I'm curious as to what exactly is going on and why those numbers were chosen.

I somewhat understand the last 2 zeros are for the fraction and precision.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

TIMEFROMPARTS (Transact-SQL)
Returns a time value for the specified time and with the specified precision.

Syntax:

```
TIMEFROMPARTS ( hour, minute, seconds, fractions, precision )
```

Arguments:

```
hour
Integer expression specifying hours.

minute
Integer expression specifying minutes.

seconds
Integer expression specifying seconds.

fractions
Integer expression specifying fractions.

precision
Integer literal specifying the precision of the time value to be returned.
```

More info you find at source. The numbers in your query are not telling anything. But the quoted formula explains what TIMEFROMPARTS expects as input arguments.

Comment: so this query was used to change an integer into time. Etc. 94459 -> 9:44:59. Any idea what the % is doing? Im not familiar with this character in SQL.

Comment: The query from question is used for generating time from one number which doesn't make really sense, and is incomplete - there is just two arguments given and TIMEFROMPARTS() function is not completed - 3 arguments missing and closing bracket missing as well.
If you ask about TIMEFROMPARTS() itself - it is changing 5 separate integers into one time value.

Answer (score 0):

The query that you posted unfortunately is incomplete, but as Amikot40 stated, the TIMEFROMPARTS function will create a value out of an array of 5 inputs. As for the percentage sign: this is called a modulo. A modulo or mod is the remainder after dividing one number by another. Example: 100 mod 9 equals 1. Because 100/9 = 11 with a remainder of 1.

In this case, the modulo is used to extract the remaining seconds after determining the amount of seconds were used to create full hours. Further down the road it's used to determine the amount of seconds remaining after determining the amount of seconds used to create full minutes. Finally, what remains are the seconds left that were not part of the hour / minute combination.